# ndb get & get_or_insert how to use ? (alway raise Exception)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I write code as below

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

__metaclass__ = type


class UserSession(ndb.Model):
    session = ndb.BlobProperty()


class KV:
    @staticmethod
    def get(id):
        r = ndb.Key(UserSession, int(id)).get()
        if r:
            return r.session

    @staticmethod
    def set(id, value):
        return UserSession.get_or_insert(int(id), session=value)

    @staticmethod
    def delete(id):
        ndb.Key(UserSession, int(id)).delete()
```

where I write

```
id = 1
key = ndb.Key(UserSession, int(id))
UserSession.get_or_insert(key, session=1)
```

the sdk raise

```
TypeError: name must be a string; received Key('UserSession', 1)
```

when I call KV.get ()

the sdk raise

File "/home/bitcoin/42btc/zapp/_plugin/auth/model/gae/user.py", line 14, in get

```
    r = ndb.Key(UserSession,int(id)).get()
```

...

BadRequestError: missing key id/name

So , how to use NDB?

Comment: Have you actually read the api documentation for ndb.  From the docs `get_or_insert(key_name, parent=None, app=None, namespace=None, context_options=None, **constructor_args)`  you see that get_or_insert called as classmethod and requires the key_name or id and not a key. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert  .  I suggest you spend some time reading the docs and tutorials on ndb

Comment: It would seem you are going down some odd paths with your choice of oldstyle classes and staticmethods.  and why the __metaclass__ assignment in the module ?

Comment: "__metaclass__ = type" means use new style of class . can you do me a favor , write a code example for me ? I read the document , but don't really konw how to do ...

Comment: You can also set the metaclass at the module level. If you set the variable __metaclass__ in a module, it will be used for all following class definitions that don't have an explicit metaclasses. New style classes inherit their metaclasses from object, so that means all old style classes. So you can do things like make all classes into new style classes by setting __metaclass__ = type
              [see this link](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/metaclasses.shtml)

Comment: Ok, I had read that article before, but I would ask why you would normally do it?  As to an example your static method `set()` does the correct thing, your  `UserSession.get_or_insert(key, session=1)` should be `UserSession.get_or_insert(int(id))`.  You class KV is really a collection of factory methods, these could just as easily be functions.  Not sure what your gaining by doing that, I suppose it's a matter choice/style.

Comment: and then    r = ndb.Key(UserSession,int(id)).get() raise BadRequestError: missing key id/name , why ? thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: I write a Class because I use my app in many different app engine , such as http://sae.sina.com.cn

Comment: @staticmethod
    def set(id, value):
        u = UserSession.get_or_insert(id=int(id))
        u.session = value
        u.put()
->
  File "/home/bitcoin/down/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3244, in _get_or_insert_async
    cls, name = args  # These must always be positional.
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Answer (score 8):

The get_or_insert() method takes a string which is only the ID part of the key, not a Key. It cannot use numeric IDs.

Comment: I see the document key has a function integer_id()
 [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_integer_id)

: Returns the integer id in the last (kind, id) pair, or None if the key has an string id or is incomplete. ---> so how to set a integer id ?

Comment: Just use Key(<class>, 42) or MyModelClass(<properties>, id=42).  But there's a whole world of things you need to worry about if you assign integer ids yourself, see the docs for allocate_ids().