# Issues with GAE allocate_ids and get_or_insert

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to combine allocate_ids() and get_or_insert() in a Python GAE app using the Datastore. I initially used

```
id = MyModel.allocate_ids(1)[0]
key = ndb.Key('MyModel', id)

m = MyModel.get_or_insert(key.id(), **{'text' : text})
```

but it raises

```
"TypeError: name must be a string; received 1L".
```

According to Guido's answer on [ndb get & get_or_insert how to use ? (alway raise Exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179240/ndb-get-get-or-insert-how-to-use-alway-raise-exception), I have to pass a string to get_or_insert, but key.string() is None. I could use

```
m = MyModel.get_or_insert(str(key.id()))
```

But it creates a new entity, e.g. with key (MyModel, '1') instead of the allocated (MyModel, 1).

What's the best way to solve this and combine both?

--

Update: edit to correct mistake on the get_or_insert as discussed in the first comment thread

Answer (score 2):

Do not do `m = MyModel.get_or_insert(str(key.id()))` you are creating a complete different key, to the key you would create using a numeric id.

If you want the functionality of `get_or_insert` using the numeric id then you will need to replicate the code in `_get_or_insert_async` with out the str check, as there is an explicit check for name being a str.  Or write your own which is simple.

Do the following inside a transaction.

```
   id = MyModel.allocate_ids(1)[0]
   key = ndb.Key('MyModel', id)
   obj = key.get()
   if not obj:
       obj = MyModel(key=key)
       obj.put()
```

The code inside `_get_or_insert_async` will be far more efficient though.

Having said all of that, if you are allocating id's then why are you using `get_or_insert` at all.  Allocate id's won't give you an numeric id that has already been allocated unless you have been randomly adding numeric id's.  That is the intent of allocate id.

This makes the use of get_or_insert with an allocated id completely redundant.

In your code you a doing a get_or_insert with only the id and no other values it seems a meaningless operation.  If you are using allocate ids you will never get an entity just create a new one, which you will then need to perform a second put to update the properties.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Re. the last point, my mistake: I pass other values to the get_or_insert but I've edited the script for the SO questions and removed that part. My goal is to allocate a set of random numeric IDs for entities that I insert later - once a user has completed an action. I need the ID before hand to issues multiple request w/ the ID (on other endpoints) at the same that I really create it, with get_or_insert. So the workflow is 1) get a random ID, 2) do stuff on the client side, 3) create the entity with the former ID, using the data from the client side.